# How to fix the warning "The data property is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead" in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

Company Profile

```
  <dashboard-card
    title="Company Profile"
    titleColor="primary"
    @click.native="componentClicked"
    id="company-profile" class="vs-con-loading__container"
    :isData= "isData"
  >
    <div class="w-full text-xl md:text-2xl font-bold">
      {{ profile.companyName }}
    </div>

    <div class="md:text-md">
      <div class="py-2">
        {{ profile.description }}
      </div>
      <table class="table-auto border-collapse">
        <tr>
          <td class="py-1 pr-2 md:pr-4 font-bold">CEO:</td>
          <td>{{ profile.ceo }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="py-1 pr-2 md:pr-4 font-bold">Exchange:</td>
          <td>{{ profile.exchange }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="py-1 pr-2 md:pr-4 font-bold">Ticker:</td>
          <td class="uppercase text-primary font-semibold">
            {{ profile.symbol }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="py-1 pr-2 md:pr-4 font-bold">Industry:</td>
          <td>{{ profile.industry }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="py-1 pr-2 font-bold">Sector:</td>
          <td>{{ profile.sector }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="pt-2">
        <vs-icon
          :icon="'icon-globe'"
          icon-pack="feather"
          class="text-primary pr-2"
        ></vs-icon>
        <a class="text-primary" :href="profile.website" target="blank">
          {{ profile.website }}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dashboard-card>
</template>

<script>
import DashboardCard from "../dashboard-card";
export default {
  name: "CompanyProfile",
  extends: DashboardCard,
  components: { DashboardCard },
  props: {
    ticker: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      profile: {},
      isData: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    ticker(value) {
      this.isData = "";
      this.getProfile(value);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isData = "";
    this.getProfile(this.ticker);
  },
  methods: {
    getProfile(ticker) {
      this.$vs.loading({
        container: "#company-profile",
        type: "point",
        scale: 0.8,
      });

      this.$api.ticker.profile(ticker).then((response) => {
        if (Object.keys(response).length == 0) {
          console.log("response is empty");
          this.isData = "404";
          this.$vs.loading.close("#company-profile > .con-vs-loading");
          return;
        }

        this.profile = response;
        this.$vs.loading.close("#company-profile > .con-vs-loading");
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("error is in company Profile ", error);
        if(error.response) {
          this.isData = error.response.status.toString();
        } else {
          this.isData = "Network Error"; 
        }
        this.$vs.loading.close("#company-profile > .con-vs-loading");
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Dashboard Card (where I'm applying the Blur effect)

```
<template>
  <BaseTHCard
    :title="title"
    :titleColor="titleColor"
    :actionable="actionable"
    :fixed-height="fixedHeight"
    @click.native="componentClicked"
  >
    <blur :isData="isData">
    <!-- DEFAULT TRADEHAT CARD HEADER SLOT -->
    <div slot="header">
      <slot name="header"> </slot>
    </div>
    <!-- DEFAULT TRADEHAT CARD MEDIA SLOT -->
    <div slot="media">
      <slot name="media"> </slot>
    </div>
    <!-- DEFAULT TRADEHAT CARD BODY SLOT -->
    <slot></slot>
    <!-- DEFAULT TRADEHAT CARD EXTRA CONTENT SLOT -->
    <div slot="extra-content">
      <slot name="extra-content"> </slot>
    </div>
    <!-- DEFAULT TRADEHAT CARD FOOTER SLOT -->
    <div slot="footer">
      <slot name="footer"> </slot>
    </div>
    </blur>
  </BaseTHCard>
</template>

<script>
import BaseTHCard from "@/components/common/base-th-card";
import blur from "../../ticker-dashboard/shared/Blur";

export default {
  name: "DashboardCard",
  extends: BaseTHCard,
  components: {
    BaseTHCard,
    blur
  },
  props: {
    isData: {
      type: String,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    titleColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "white",
    },
    fixedHeight: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    actionable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm getting two following warnings from vue:-
[image: use prop default value]
[image]

I am setting the `isData` data option in the `CompanyProfile` component and passing it as a prop to `DashboardCard` component and sending that `isData` prop value to the `blurr` component. The functionality works fine but I'm getting the above mentioned warnings from vue. What should be the approach to fix them.

Comment: Just rename `isData` in Dashboard Card component.

Comment: The `BaseTHCard` contains the same `isData` prop (Apparently). So you can omit this prop in `CompanyProfile`